# Accessing all properties of custom dependency property after PropertyChangedCallback

Tags: wpf, binding, dependency-properties

I have an example Dependency Property defined like this:

```
public Polyline Shape
{
    get { return (Polyline)GetValue(ShapeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ShapeProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ShapeProperty =
DependencyProperty.Register("Shape", typeof(Polyline), 
typeof(CustomControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null,
FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, onShapeAdded));
```

I'm setting it like this:

```
<local:CustomControl>
    <local:CustomControl.Shape>
        <Polyline Points="0,180 0,80 70,80 90,180 0,180" />
    </local:CustomControl.Shape>
</local:CustomControl>
```

It's Callback looks like this:

```
private static void onShapeAdded(DependencyObject d,
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Polyline control = (Polyline)e.NewValue;
    //control.Points is always null
}
```

Why Points collection is always null during callback? (It happens with every property) At the end Points are set so I guess I am accesing my control too soon but when and how should I access control with all it's properties set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `onShapeAdded` method is actually the event handler for the `PropertyChangedCallback` when means that it will fire when the Shape property changes.  This change is clearly being fired when the `Polyline` is added and before the `Points` property is initialized.

You could try getting around this by defining the `Polyline` as a resource, meaning it will be initialized before it is added to the control.  For example:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Polyline x:Key="myPolyline" Points="0,180 0,80 70,80 90,180 0,180" />
</Window.Resources>

<local:CustomControl Shape="{DynamicResource myPolyline}"/>
```

I believe the `Polyline` will be fully initialized if added in this way.

Comment: Yeah this is definitely a workaround but In my case I will be adding several CustomControls and defining about 5 polylines with unique keys and binding them doesn't look good. There must be a better way

Comment: Why doesn't this look good?  It is not actually binding - using resources is different from binding.  The XAML is actually simpler and more maintainable (all the `Polylines` are defined in one place).  If you wanted it closer, you could define the `Polylines` in the Resources of the CustomControl.  Maybe I'm not understanding your overall goal.  The only other option I can think of is to attach a Listener to the `Polyline` in your OnShapeAdded method to listen for changes to the `Points` property of the `Polyline`.

Comment: I have added listener to `Loaded` even of my Polyline and there I am checking my Points and other properties